# Read strings from file with whitespaces in C

Tags: c, string, file, text, whitespace

I'm making quiz program in c and part of my program is to getting questions from text file, count and print them. But when i want to print or count them every time it sees whitespace it skips to other variable. How can i solve it?

That's my txt file

```
What is the Capital of France? Paris Roma London Istanbul Belgrad
```

And how it seems in my program.

```
What
a)is
b)the
c)capital
d)of
e)France
```

That's how i get questions

```
    FILE *fp = fopen("fp.txt", "a+");
    gets(questions[n].question_part);        
    gets(questions[n].a);
    gets(questions[n].b);
    gets(questions[n].c);
    gets(questions[n].d);
    gets(questions[n].e);
    questions[n].answer=getch();
    fprintf(fp, "%s %s %s %s %s %s %c", questions[n].question_part, questions[n].a, questions[n].b, questions[n].c, questions[n].d, questions[n].e, questions[n].answer);
    n++;
```

How i count

```
    int x=0;
    while(!feof(fp)){   
    fscanf(fp, "%s %s %s %s %s %s %c", questions[x].question_part, questions[x].a, questions[x].b, questions[x].c, questions[x].d, questions[x].e, questions[x].answer);
    x++;}
    n=x;
```

And how i print

```
    FILE *fp;           
    fp = fopen("fp.txt", "r");
    int y;
    for(y=0;y<n;y++) 
    {       
        printf("\nQuestion number %d:\n",y+1);
        printf("Question: %s\n",questions[y].question_part);
        printf("a)%s\n",questions[y].a);
        printf("b)%s\n",questions[y].b);
        printf("c)%s\n",questions[y].c);
        printf("d)%s\n",questions[y].d);
        printf("e)%s\n",questions[y].e);
        printf("Answer: %c\n",questions[y].answer);
    }
```

Comment: First of all, never ***ever*** use `gets`! It's a [dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) function that have even been removed in the C specifications. Use e.g. [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) to read lines instead.

Comment: you need to use another seperator than a whitespace when writing to and reading from file, otherwise there is no way the fscanf functionality will work,

Comment: Also please read [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `%s` format for [`fscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) reads *space delimited* strings.

I suggest you solve this by writing the question and the options on separate lines. For example by

```
fprintf(fp, "%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%c\n", questions[n].question_part, questions[n].a, questions[n].b, questions[n].c, questions[n].d, questions[n].e, questions[n].answer);
```

Now you can read each line with [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets).

Answer (score 0):

Try using another seperator, e.g. '_' change

```
 fprintf(fp, "%s %s %s %s %s %s %c", questions[n].question_part, questions[n].a, questions[n].b, questions[n].c, questions[n].d, questions[n].e, questions[n].answer);
```

to

```
fprintf(fp, "%s_%s_%s_%s_%s_%s_%c", questions[n].question_part, questions[n].a, questions[n].b, questions[n].c, questions[n].d, questions[n].e, questions[n].answer);
```

and

```
fscanf(fp, "%s %s %s %s %s %s %c", questions[x].question_part, questions[x].a, questions[x].b, questions[x].c, questions[x].d, questions[x].e, questions[x].answer);
```

to

```
fscanf(fp, "%s_%s_%s_%s_%s_%s_%c", questions[x].question_part, questions[x].a, questions[x].b, questions[x].c, questions[x].d, questions[x].e, questions[x].answer);
```

if you want to keep one question with answers on one line, otherwise i think you should go with the answer that suggest printing each part on a newline.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you can not control the input file, consider using the '?' as the terminator the question (assuming this will hold true for all questions).

One proposal: consider using pointer to 'current' question - `q` in the following exapmle, it will make code easier.

```
struct question *q ;   // whatever structure name describe the question/answer.
q = &question[x] ;
fscanf(fp, "%[^?]? %s %s %s %s %s %c",
    q->question_part, 
    q->a, q->b, q->c, q->d, q->e, q->answer);
```